# Running cat /proc/cpuinfo in glib

Tags: c, glib

I've been trying to look for questions  on how to use `g_spawn_sync()` and they said that  it is good to use when you want to execute a command in the terminal besides using pipes.

The only thing I can't figure out now is why the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo` doesn't work. `error->message` returns `(No such file or directory)`but if I use commands like `ls` or `cat` alone, it works. I also tried running `cd /proc && cat cpuinfo` but it gives me the same error.

I'm not an expert of glib but I read in the manual that I can use `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH` so that it will check my `PATH` for the commands I can use without including the absolute path for the command.

I have the following code:

```
gchar *argv[] = { "cat /proc/cpuinfo", NULL };
char *output = NULL; // will contain command output
GError *error = NULL;
int exit_status = 0;
if (!g_spawn_sync(NULL, argv, NULL, G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH, NULL, NULL, 
                &output, NULL, &exit_status, &error))
{
    printf("[getHardwareInfo] DEBUG: Error on g_spawn_sync %s.\n", error->message);

}
```

Comment: What does cat do in reality? It just read the content of file. You can just do simple Unix file read operation to read cpuinfo file.

Comment: My problem is not on the cat command but why I get the error when I run the entire command `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: If you made argv an actual array, you'd be closer to what you need: `gchar *argv[] = { "/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo", NULL }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: Do not use `g_spawn_command_line_sync()` unless you really know what you are doing.**

Firstly, the actual problem you are hitting: John Szakmeister’s comment was correct: `g_spawn_sync()` takes an array of arguments, the first one of which is the path to the program to execute (or to look for in `$PATH`, if you’ve specified `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH`). By passing the array `{ "cat /proc/cpuinfo", NULL }`, you are saying that you want to run the program `cat /proc/cpuinfo` with no arguments, **not** the program `cat` with the argument `/proc/cpuinfo`.

However, there are many other problems here, and I think it’s important to mention them before people start cargo-culting this code, because they have **security implications**:

- As LegalProgrammer says, why are you spawning `cat` when you could just call [`g_file_get_contents()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-file-get-contents)?
- Failing that, use [`GSubprocess`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSubprocess.html) instead of `g_spawn_*()`. It’s a more modern API, which allows you to monitor the lifecycle of the spawned process more easily, as well as getting streaming I/O in and out of the subprocess.
- Do not ignore the warnings in the manual about the security implications of using `g_spawn_command_line_sync()`. There are several:

  - It will run the first matching program found in your `$PATH`, so if an attacker has control of your `$PATH`, or write access to any directory in that `$PATH` (such as `~/.local/bin`), you will end up running an attacker-controlled program.
  - It’s a synchronous function, so will block on the subprocess completing, which could take unbounded time. Your program will be unresponsive for that time.
  - It returns the output in a single allocation, rather than as a stream, so if the subprocess returns many megabytes of output, you may hit allocation failures and abort.
  - The obvious next step from “`g_spawn_command_line_sync()` seems to do what I want” is “let’s use `g_strdup_printf()` to put together a command to run with it”, and then you have [shell injection vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), where an attacker who controls any of the parameters to that `printf()` can twist the entire shell command to execute their arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really having a hard time looking for examples wherein it shows when to use each of those functions. I'm no way a Glib expert so I'm sorry if it my answer ticked you off.

Comment: Your answer didn’t tick me off, but I would not want anyone to blindly copy and paste that code without knowing the consequences. If there are bits of the GLib API documentation which you think could be improved please do file a bug (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib) with specific examples of what is missing or would be helpful to add. Then everyone can benefit in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my question here. After reading the manual again, I decided to use another function, **`g_spawn_command_line_sync`**, which is simpler to use than `g_spawn_sync`.

> A simple version of `g_spawn_sync()` with little-used parameters removed, taking a command line instead of an argument vector. See `g_spawn_sync()` for full details. `command_line` will be parsed by `g_shell_parse_argv()`. Unlike `g_spawn_sync()`, the `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH` flag is enabled. Note that `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH` can have security implications, so consider using `g_spawn_sync()` directly if appropriate. Possible errors are those from `g_spawn_sync()` and those from `g_shell_parse_argv()`.

Here is my new code:

```
char *output = NULL; // will contain command output
GError *error = NULL;
gint exit_status = 0;
if (!g_spawn_command_line_sync("cat /proc/cpuinfo", &output, NULL, &exit_status, &error))
{
    printf("[getHardwareInfo] DEBUG: Error on g_spawn_command_line_sync %s.\n", error->message);
```

Comment: This answer is dangerous advice to anyone who does not fully understand what they are doing. See my answer for details.